# how to invoke a URLSession publisher when a timer publisher fires

Tags: swift, combine

I want to invoke a URLSession publisher based on a timer publisher every 60 minutes.

It seems like this should be possible but not aware how to do it:

For instance;

```
struct Response: Codable {
    // ... some fields here
}


class MyClass: ObservableObject {
  @Published var response: Response? = nil
  var cancelable : AnyCancelable? 
  func connectPoller() {
    let timer = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 60 * 60, runLoop: .main, mode: .default)
    // how to chain this?
    // want to connect the timer to invoke the data task
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "some-url-here")!).tryMap() { element -> Data in
            guard let httpResponse = element.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                    throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
                }
            return element.data
        }.decode(type: Response?.self, decoder: JSONDecoder()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        .replaceError(with: nil).assign(to: \.response, on: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use flatMap?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var response: Response? = nil
    
    var cancelable : AnyCancellable?
    
    func connectPoller() {
        let timer = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 60 * 60, runLoop: .main, mode: .default)
            .autoconnect()  //<= here
        
        cancelable = timer
            .flatMap { _ in
                URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "some-url-here")!).tryMap() { element -> Data in
                    guard let httpResponse = element.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                          httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                        throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
                    }
                    return element.data
                }
                .decode(type: Response?.self, decoder: JSONDecoder()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                .replaceError(with: nil)
            }
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main) //<= here
            .assign(to: \.response, on: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to transform the Timer publisher into the URLSession dataTask publisher, you'll want to use `flatMap`. In addition, you'll want to make sure that the publisher chain can't complete, because the timer will stop firing at that point. So, you'll need to do a little more aggressive cleansing of the errors inside the `flatMap` so that they don't propagate further down the chain.

```
class MyClass: ObservableObject {
  @Published var response: Response? = nil
  var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
  func connectPoller() {
    cancellable = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .default)
        .autoconnect()
        .flatMap { _ in
            URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "https://google.com")!)
                .flatMap { element -> AnyPublisher<Data,Never> in
                    guard let httpResponse = element.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                                    httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                        return Just(Data()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                                    }
                    return Just(element.data).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
                .decode(type: Response?.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .replaceError(with: nil)
        }
        .print()
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .assign(to: \.response, on: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: the nesting is what I want to avoid. I was hoping to do something like 
`timer.connect().invoke(nsurlSession....).assign(...)`

Comment: @AvnerBarr your idea is not good 'cause.. what if the request fail .. then you cant trigger it ..  it terminates once error out( or completes)

Comment: @AvnerBarr I agree with the comment above -- if you want the chain to keep functioning on each timer call, you can't let the URL session trigger a failure. That's why the `flatMap` is necessary. You could, however, create your own `invoke` function that wraps all of that functionality cleanly so that you could re-use it when necessary and not have it clutter your codebase.